# Listview Increase Size of Selected Index

Tags: android, android-listview

hello i am having a problem with listview. i want to expand the size of selected image inside listview for example i have a listivew and when i click on an item it increases in size than other rows in listview my sample code for onitemclick listner is

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    if(civ!=null){

        civ.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }




     civ = (CustomImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.civ_shelfBook_BookImage);
     LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) civ.getLayoutParams();

        params.height = 0;
        params.width = 0;
        civ.setLayoutParams(params);

     updateView(position);

    DetailActivity.shelfID = civ.getShelfID();
    DetailActivity.currentlySelected =position;



}
```

Comment: try this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: Use this https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom listview adapter and do the following in the `getView` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

        holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image));

    if(position == selectedPosition) {  
        convertView.setLayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT);// Set value as required
      // Change row and image size here

    } else {
        convertView.setLayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
   ImageView image;
}
```

Comment: ViewHolder type was not found

Comment: this is not comprehensive enough

Comment: For where can we get the selectedPosition variable in the adapter?